# How to make trposition start with 1 while looping through table

Tags: jquery

when clicked on submit button , how to make start tr position start with 1 
right now once clicked on submit it starts with zero
This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.updatepacorder', function(event)
{
        var allpacs = [];
        $('#sort > tbody  > tr').each(function(i)
        {
                var pacid = $(this).attr('pac_id');
                var id = i+1;
                var pacjson = {
                        "pacid": pacid,
                        "trposition": i
                }
                allpacs.push(pacjson);
        });
        var requestdata = {
                "pac_details": allpacs,
        };
        var reqested_data = JSON.stringify(requestdata);
        console.log(reqested_data);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/z74VH/10/

Could you please let me know how to make tr start with 1 .

Comment: you can declare var i=0; outside each function, no need to pass it in the loop ,i guess thats how it starts with 1

Comment: Your counter `i` always starts at zero. If you want to start at `1`, then use `var pacjson = { "pacid": pacid, "trposition": id }`.

Comment: Whats the deal with `var id` anyways? You're not using it. Maybe you just wanted to use `id` instead of `i` in the pacjson object. Everything's ok, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different variable declared outside the loop than the loop index, or just add `i++;` as the first statement in loop. Or use the `id` variable which contains the incremented value of loop index.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, the point where you want to start from 1 instead of 0 is the `trposition` member of the `pacjson` object?

If so, it's quite easy: merely write `trposition: i + 1` rather than `trposition: i`.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` will always start from `0` because it is the index of the first element in the array. If you want to start from 1 you need to increment `i` as you already did `var id = i+1` and use `id` instead of `i`:

```
 $('#sort > tbody  > tr').each(function(i)
 {
      var pacid = $(this).attr('pac_id');
            var id = i+1;
            var pacjson = {
                    "pacid": pacid,
                    "trposition": id // <- here
            }
            allpacs.push(pacjson);
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to include all the ittems